# Accessing Objective-C variables/functions from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, import, bridging-header

Suppose I have a connector named Connector.m (written in Objective-C). And I would like to create a new connector written using Swift, named Connector.swift. I would like to access all of the variables and methods from Swift. I have create a bridging-header and write import of the header file of the Connector. But I can't access any of global variables on the Objective-C class.

**Connector.m**

```
NSString * const kHTTP_METHOD_GET = @"GET";
```

**Connector.swift**

```
public class Connector: NSObject {

    var parentConnector : Connector

    override init() {
        self.parentConnector = Connector
    }

    func test() {
        print(parentConnector.kHTTP_METHOD_GET) //--> ERROR : Value of type 'Connector' has no member 'kHTTP_METHOD_GET'
    }

}
```

Is it possible to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have header file like this...

```
{project-name}-Bridging-Header.h
```

Add your class file in  Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "Connector.h"
```

And Put your below code in  **Connector.h** file..Because in Bridging-Header.h will only import header file

```
NSString * const kHTTP_METHOD_GET = @"GET";
```

to on top of @interface scope..

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in Connector.h.

```
extern NSString * const kHTTP_METHOD_GET;
```

Include Connector.h to your bridging header file.

Comment: Is there need to use `extern`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the methods/variables in Connector.m also need to be public for it to work.

Comment: How to do that? Btw the variables in Connector.m is out of @implementation scope..

Comment: just add public `public NSString * const kHTTP_METHOD_GET = @"GET";`

Comment: Also, aren't you trying to access an instance of the swift object, which has no member named `kHTTP_METHOD_GET`? I think your swift class needs a different name.

Comment: We can't add '@' symbol outside of '@interface' scope, and the global variable can't be on '@interface'.

Comment: I am saying, your `parentConnector` is of type Connector.swift, not Connector.h/m. So it does not have the member that you want. You need to make parentConnector the type of your objective-c class.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use-case for the [Adapter Pattern](https://github.com/ochococo/Design-Patterns-In-Swift/blob/master/source/structural/adapter.swift). But you should be able to access Objective-C code easily.

Make sure your bridging header file is named like this:

```
{your-project-name}-Bridging-Header.h
```

Inside your bridging header add the following:

```
#import "Connector.m"
```

Then you have to make sure the compiler knows about your bridging header:

**Click your root project > Select your target app > Build Settings**

Then scroll down until you see this:

[image]

Make sure your bridging header is listed, build and you should have access to your Objective-C code.

Comment: Thanks, but can we importing the implementation files instead of header files? I got an error while importing the implementation files, it says not found. And yes, I have make sure that the bridging-header is listed.

Comment: hmm.. not sure about that, I just know how to access objective-c using the standard bridging header